# Finding multiple minimum value with NetLogo

Tags: list, netlogo, min

I have two breeds; firms and consumers. My consumers apply to random n of firms, and then firms select the consumers who have the lowest wage demand.

Firms have a labor demand, consumers have a wage-rate, each labor demand and wage rate is firms and consumer specific.

Labor demand can be more then applicant to a firm. I want to choose the minimum count of those two agent set, and make my worker-set's count accordingly.

```
to select-workers ; firm specific action
  ask consumers [ set occupational-status 0] ; I'm setting every consumer/workers unemployed at the beginning
    set applicants no-turtles ; i have an applicant agent set representing applied consumers to work
    set worker-set no-turtles ; i have an worker-set which will turn in to an agent set holding my workers
  ask consumers [ ask n-of M firms [ set applicants (turtle-set myself applicants)   ; i have constructed my agent set
    let appl-count count applicants
    let demand-count count laborDemand
    let myList ( list appl-count demand-count )
] 

end
```

My problem begins at the end of the code, I want to transfer my applicants to my worker-set but if applicant count is less than my labor demand, program does not work properly. Also I should choose consumers with the lowest minimum wage.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the code you wrote that didn't work properly, and say what happened? It would help us understand your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach`. It's not pretty but it can work... something like

```
  let list_value [my_value] of citizens
  set list_value sort-by > list_value
  let nb_nomination [1 1] ;;of repetitions
  foreach nb_nomination [
     ask one-of citizens with[my_value = first list_value][
       set happy TRUE
     ]
   set list_value but-first list_value
   ]
```